# How run solr from command line?

Tags: solr

I run:

```
solr@server:~$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/solr/log4j.properties -Xss256k -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /var/solr/logs -jar /opt/solr-5.5.4/server/start.jar --module=http
```

And I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 8983
```

Comment: What is your Solr version?

Comment: Now I use 5.5.4

Comment: Upgrade Solr and use `bin/solr`.

Comment: @MatsLindh I want to run solr from the command line. It's impossible?

Comment: @Simon As I said, use bin/solr in a more recent version.

Comment: @MatsLindh I want to run solr from the command line. If you do not know how to do this, then say so.

Comment: @Simon Well, [that's what `bin/solr` does. It runs Solr. From the command line](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr).

Comment: .. in your command where you're attempting to run start.jar manually, you have a space around before your port number, making Java try to load a class named 8983 and not the jar you've provided.

Comment: @MatsLindh "you have a space around before your port number" Many thanks. Now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @MatsLindh, use solr script.

In terminal navigate to /opt/solr.

```
cd /opt/solr
```

you can see solr.sh file inside bin folder and hit the below command

```
bin/solr start
```

For other options use help command

```
bin/solr -h
```

Comment: I need to run without bin/solr.

Comment: use start.jar which can be found inside server folder /opt/solr/server

Comment: `cd /opt/solr/server` and `java -jar start.jar --module=http`